# Check max value from three variables by using preprocessor in C

Tags: c, if-statement, c-preprocessor

I want to print the value of the variable, which has the highest value. I want to do this by using the preprocessor, but I don't know how to do this. It's easy to do this by using if-else, but how to do that by using preprocessor?
This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX(a,b,c)
#if a > (b && c)
#   define a
#endif
#if b > (a && c)
#   define b
#else
#   define c
#endif

int main (void)
{
    int wynik;
    int a = 6;
    int b = 13;
    int c = 9;
    wynik = MAX(a,b,c);
    printf("%i", wynik);

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the errors from my terminal

```
E:\skrypty_c>gcc -o Cwiczenie12_4.exe Cwiczenie12_4.c
Cwiczenie12_4.c: In function 'main':
Cwiczenie12_4.c:17:11: error: expected identifier or '(' before '=' token
     int c = 9;
           ^
Cwiczenie12_4.c:18:23: error: expected expression before ';' token
     wynik = MAX(a,b,c);
```

Comment: `#define` requires a single "line", and cannot include other `#`-style pre-processor directives like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preprocessor cannot be used for that. Preprocessor does not know anything about the c variables and sysntax.

You cant use any preprocesor conditional expressions in the #defines.

if you want to use macro to find max of 3 tokens you need to use C expressions for that as it will be evaluated runtime (or compile time), not during the preprocessing

```
#define MAX(a,b,c)  (a) > (b) ? ((a) > (c) ? (a) : ((c) > (b) ? c : (b))) : ((b) > (c) ? (b) : (c))
```

Answer (score 4):

That's not how it works. Your max-of-three macro would be something like

```cpp
#define MAX(a, b, c) ((a) <= (b)? (b) <= (c)? (c) : (b) : (a) <= (c)? (c) : (a))
```

but frankly, it would be much better as a function:

```cpp
inline int max(int a, int b, int c) {
    if(a <= b) {
        if(b <= c) return c;
        return b;
    }
    return a <= c? c : a;
}
```

Comment: The marginal advantage of the macro is it works on non-`int` values.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check the value of runtime variables through preprocessor conditionals. They can check only the values of preprocessor level symbols. For example

```
#define A 5

#if (A  > 3)
...
#endif
```

Looking at the way you used `#define` and `#if`, **my guess** is that you meant defining some sort of *preprocessor level function* having `#define` a similar role of `def func ():` in Python. **That's not how it works.**

- **`#define A expr`** just replaces the *symbol* `A` with *expression* `expr` in the current source file **before** compilation. No occurrences of `A`, no substitutions
- **`#define A(b,c) expr`** is like the previous one, but uses `b,c` like function parameters, and they are expanded in the replaced in *expression* `expr` using the values passed when the macro is called.
- **`#if expr`** or **`#ifdef symbol`** or **`#ifndef symbol`** are ways to check the value or even the simple definition of symbols previously defined through `#define`s (or through compiler option -D) in order perform *conditional compilation* of whole sections of code. These sections are closed with `#endif`, and alternative sections in case of false conditions can be compiled using `#else` and `#elif` directives.

  ---

What you can do, and I suspect it was your actual purpose, is to define a macro finding the maximum value among its parameters:

```
#define MAX(a,b,c) \
    (((a>b) && (a>c))? a : ((b>a) && (b>c))? b : c ))
```

I used *ternary operator* to calculate the max value.

**Note:** the `\` character allows to place a macro on multiple lines. It needs to be the last character of the line.

Comment: What's this `a > (b && c)`? Did you mean `a > b && a > c`?

Comment: @WeatherVane as I explained I have no idea. it is just the expression used by OP in those #ifs

Comment: @it checks if a is greater than `1` or `0` depending of the values of the `b` and `c` (sometimes their parts)

Comment: Considering it is supposed to find the maximum of three values...

Comment: @WeatherVane it is not the answer

Comment: @RobertoCaboni the question is clear and the answer should answer this question

Comment: I can understand your defensiveness but considering the OP's code has `int a = 6; int b = 13; int c = 9; wynik = MAX(a,b,c);` the intention seems pretty clear.

Comment: OTOH I like another of your answers.

Comment: @P__J__ I changed my strategy and performed a major edit to my answer. I tried to explain preprocessor basics tailored on OP's misunderstanding